# If a column value is between a range, get a corresponding value

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have the two data frames -

- Dataframe 1:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
Numbers
40500
4400025
14515
51432", header = TRUE)
```

- Dataframe 2:

```
df2 <- read.table(text = "
ColumnA   ColumnB    ReturnC   ReturnD
32000       41400      rose      apple
51400       57389      orchid    orange
12523       16357      jasmine   grapes
10528       11034      lily      melon ", header = TRUE)
```

This is what I want -- Check if each value from `Numbers` in dataframe 1 is between `ColumnA` and `ColumnB` of dataframe 2. If it is, I want the corresponding `ReturnC` and `ReturnD` from dataframe 2 in the output.

If it is not, I want `NA`.

E.g. `51432` is in between column A and column B.  Orchid and orange are the corresponding values in dataframe 2 for that intersection. This is how the final dataset will look like:

Final:

```
Numbers     Output1      Output2
40500        rose        apple
4400025      NA          NA
14515        jasmine     grapes 
51432        orchid      orange
```

How should I do this in `R`? -- Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `left_join` + `join_by` from `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

left_join(df1, df2, by = join_by(between(Numbers, ColumnA, ColumnB)))

#   Numbers ColumnA ColumnB ReturnC ReturnD
# 1   40500   32000   41400    rose   apple
# 2 4400025      NA      NA    <NA>    <NA>
# 3   14515   12523   16357 jasmine  grapes
# 4   51432   51400   57389  orchid  orange
```

Comment: Note that `join_by` was added in dplyr version 1.1.0 on Jan 29, 2023, so you might have to update to make this work

Comment: Why is your last value in ColumnA 51400,  in the example of OP it is 10528

Comment: @TarJae `left_join` keeps the order of the first data (i.e. `df1`). ColumnA and ColumnB are from `df2` and are joined to `df1`, so their order changed. The last `Numbers` is `51432`, which is between `51400` and `57389` from `df2`. That's reasonable.

Comment: Could you please: Check this `bind_cols(df1, df2) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Return"), ~ifelse(between(Numbers, ColumnA, ColumnB), ., NA)))`. ? It is not correct.

Comment: @TarJae What you do is row-wise comparison. But I think the OP want cross comparison. `df1` and `df2` are not necessary to have equal number of rows, so `bind_cols(df1, df2)` does not make sense. Your code fails in the 4th row because 51432 (4th `Numbers`) is not between 10528 (4th `ColumnA`) and 11034 (4th `ColumnB`).